# excel vba calling variant using a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have 112 variants each of the 112 variants list building numbers specific to a company.  I need to loop through all 112 variants to search for a match based on user input.  I tried making a separate array composed of all the variant names of the 112 and setting this as a variable.  Putting this variable into a loop I hoped it would call each of the 112 variants, but it does not work.

When I run the code I get Runtime Error 13:  Type Mismatch

How can I cycle through multiple variants one at a time?  Thanks!

```
Match = False

Do

    k = 3

    k = k + 1

    str = Range("E" & k).Value

    Dim TitleArray As Variant

    TitleArray = Split(str, Chr(32))

    For i = 0 To UBound(TitleArray)         'Loops through text in title column

        Dim ScanWord, CmdFac As String

        ScanWord = TitleArray(i)

        For j = 1 To UBound(cmdArray)       'Loops through CmdArray

            Dim CmdAtitle As Variant

            CmdAtitle = cmdArray(j)

            For l = 2 To UBound(CmdAtitle)

                Dim TempFac As String

                TempFac = CmdAtitle(l)

                If (TempFac = ScanWord) Then

                    Fac = CmdAtitle(1)

                    Match = True

                    Exit For

                End If

            Next l

            If Match = True Then

                Exit For

            End If

        Next j

        If (Match = True) Then

            Exit For

        End If

    Next i

    If (Match = True) Then

        Range("AL" & k).Value = TempFac

    End If

Loop Until Match = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to call specific variants using a variable representing a variant name.  Instead I put the data into a worksheet and created an array based on a range.  A loop cycled through worksheet redefining the array each pass.  I created the array using the following post from Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859531/excel-vba-populate-array-with-range-from-specific-sheet